# Usage Java module system for Kotlin project

Tags: kotlin, java-module, java-platform-module-system

In our purely Kotlin project we would like to use flexible Java 9 module system. Otherwise we have to use `internal` visibility modifier too often to hide internal Kotlin module functionality from other Kotlin modules.

Is it possible to use **Jigsaw** in Kotlin?

Comment: I found your question interesting and did some research. I did not find a way to create something like module-info.kt or give an option to the Kotlin Maven or Gradle plugins to have it automatically created. However it is possible to put `module-info.java` into `src/main/kotlin`.  It's easier with Maven, because everything is put under `target/classes`. Just take sure, that the Kotlin plugin is triggered before the Maven compiler plugin (eg. put it in phase `process-sources`) and that you use a version of the Maven compiler that understands `META-INF/versions` from kotlin.stdlib (e.g. 3.11.0).

Comment: For Gradle its described here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#configure-with-java-modules-jpms-enabled. `--patch-module` is needed, because with Gradle Kotlin classes and Java classes are placed into different directories. You can ignore the warning from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#kotlin-and-java-sources and add sth. like `sourceSets { main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin' }`. If you have specified the JVM target for Kotlin, you must now do the same for Java (e.g. `compileJava { sourceCompatibility = '9'; targetCompatibility = '9' }`.